# SatScan (and rsatscan) writing empty shapefile

Tags: r, shapefile, spatial-statistics, satscan

This is a reinterpretation of a previous question I've asked, refining the problem statement after some more troubleshooting. I'm implementing SatScan (v9.6.1) in R using `rsatscan` (v1.0.3, downloaded from CRAN) on a number of different diseases (line-level cases, lat/long coordinates) and have been wondering why in some instances, SatScan, and `rsatscan` is writing empty shapefiles to my working directory, resulting in a `readOGR` "no features found error" in the `satscan()` call in R (source documentation [here](https://rdrr.io/github/Kenkleinman/rsatscan/src/R/satscan.R)). I've also confirmed that SatScan returns empty shapefiles when run on the data for which `satscan()` in R was throwing the `readOGR` error. Developing a minimum working example for this problem is proving tough, as the only difference between the disease-specific files being input is the number of cases and the data are jurisdiction-specific. The SatScan user guide only says the following regarding shapefile generation:

> Shape File: For spatial and space-time analyses, SaTScan will create a Shape file that can be used to depict the detected clusters in geographical information systems. Two different files are created with extensions .shp and .shx. The KML and shapefile can only be generated when the geographical coordinates are specified using
> latitudes and longitudes. The names of these output files are the same as the names of the text output format files, but with different filename extensions.

If no clusters are detected and thus, an empty shapefile is being written, then how is the `rsatscan` implementation supposed to work? Or, is there a minimum number of observations I'm supposed to input into SatScan so something gets written to the shapefile?

Params, R Session info below:

```
#Set options related to the input tab 
ss.options(list(CaseFile = "SessionR.cas", 
               PrecisionCaseTimes = 3,
               StartDate = format(Sys.Date()-366, "%Y/%m/%d"), #366 initially
               EndDate = format(Sys.Date()-1, "%Y/%m/%d"),
               CoordinatesFile = "SessionR.geo",
               CoordinatesType = 1
               ))

#Set options related to the analysis tab 
ss.options(list(AnalysisType = 4,
               ModelType = 2,
               ScanAreas = 1,
               TimeAggregationUnits = 3,
               TimeAggregationLength = 1
))

#Set options related to the output tab 
ss.options(list(ResultsFile = "xxyy.txt",  #doesn't appear to be writing
               OutputGoogleEarthKML = "n",
               OutputShapefiles = "y",
               MostLikelyClusterEachCentroidASCII = "y",
               MostLikelyClusterEachCentroidDBase = "y",
               MostLikelyClusterCaseInfoEachCentroidASCII = "n",
               MostLikelyClusterCaseInfoEachCentroidDBase = "n",
               CensusAreasReportedClustersASCII = "y",
               CensusAreasReportedClustersDBase = "y",
               IncludeRelativeRisksCensusAreasASCII = "n",
               IncludeRelativeRisksCensusAreasDBase = "n",
               SaveSimLLRsASCII = "n",
               SaveSimLLRsDBase = "n"
))

#Set advanced options 
ss.options(list(StudyPeriodCheckType=1, #relax geography bounds per cop
               GeographicalCoordinatesCheckType = 1,
               UseDistanceFromCenterOption = "n",
               MaxSpatialSizeInDistanceFromCenter = 1,
               NonCompactnessPenalty = 1,
               MaxTemporalSize = as.integer(paramFilter$Max_Size),
               MaxTemporalSizeInterpretation = 1,  
               ProspectiveStartDate = format(Sys.Date()-366, "%Y/%m/%d"),  #Not sure if this parameter is correct?
               CriteriaForReportingSecondaryClusters = 1,
               LogRunToHistoryFile = "y",
               Version = "9.6.1"))

td <- tempdir()
write.ss.prm(td, "SessionR")
write.cas(as.data.frame(casfile), td, "SessionR")
write.geo(as.data.frame(geofile), td, "SessionR")
session <- try(satscan(td, "SessionR", sslocation = "C:/SaTScan", cleanup = FALSE, verbose = F), silent = T)
```

```
sessionInfo()
        R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] stringr_1.5.0    purrr_1.0.1      kableExtra_1.3.4 leaflet_2.1.2    rmarkdown_2.21   keyring_1.3.1    mailR_0.8        rJava_1.0-6      lubridate_1.9.2 
[10] readr_2.1.4      rsatscan_1.0.3   rgdal_1.6-6      sp_1.6-0         readxl_1.4.2     dplyr_1.1.2     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] xfun_0.39         htmlwidgets_1.6.2 lattice_0.21-8    tzdb_0.4.0        vctrs_0.6.2       tools_4.3.0       crosstalk_1.2.0   generics_0.1.3    parallel_4.3.0   
[10] tibble_3.2.1      fansi_1.0.4       pkgconfig_2.0.3   R.oo_1.25.0       assertthat_0.2.1  webshot_0.5.4     lifecycle_1.0.3   compiler_4.3.0    munsell_0.5.0    
[19] htmltools_0.5.5   pillar_1.9.0      crayon_1.5.2      R.utils_2.12.2    tidyselect_1.2.0  rvest_1.0.3       digest_0.6.31     stringi_1.7.12    fastmap_1.1.1    
[28] grid_4.3.0        colorspace_2.1-0  cli_3.6.1         magrittr_2.0.3    utf8_1.2.3        foreign_0.8-84    withr_2.5.0       scales_1.2.1      bit64_4.0.5      
[37] timechange_0.2.0  httr_1.4.6        bit_4.0.5         cellranger_1.1.0  R.methodsS3_1.8.2 hms_1.1.3         evaluate_0.21     knitr_1.42        viridisLite_0.4.2
[46] rlang_1.1.1       glue_1.6.2        xml2_1.3.4        svglite_2.1.1     rstudioapi_0.14   vroom_1.6.3       R6_2.5.1          systemfonts_1.0.4
```

Comment: So its a bug in the `rsatscan` package? The `SatScan` system creates an empty file, but `rsatscan` doesn't handle that case gracefully? Report to the `rsatscan` authors? This package is going to need some serious work soon anyway since the `readOGR` function and spatial data classes are not long for this earth.

Comment: Yeah I'll certainly notify them, hopefully the reintegration of the package on CRAN is a sign of a better future for this package. Thanks for all the help/responses!

Comment: I'd avoid it if possible - SatScan is not open source and so is not compatible with modern scientific practices. Other packages are available on CRAN which are open source and some even implement some of the algorithms in SatScan.